# PHP Iterate through JSON and save via T-SQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I have PHP code that returns the values below from a website I have subscribed to, my question is how can I loop through this array and echo each line? Along with that, I want to insert each record in a MS-SQL database, if possible, preferably through a bulk insert.

```json
{
  "count": 8,
  "messages": [
    {
      "t": 1638413506,
      "f": 1073743361,
      "tp": "evt",
      "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.026467, 121.721675\nTime: 2021-12-02 10:51:46\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.026467,121.721675",
      "x": 121.721674983,
      "y": 17.0264666677,
      "rt": 0,
      "p": {}
    },
    {
      "t": 1638415192,
      "f": 1073743361,
      "tp": "evt",
      "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.023507, 121.721527\nTime: 2021-12-02 11:19:52\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.023507,121.721527",
      "x": 121.721526655,
      "y": 17.0235066672,
      "rt": 0,
      "p": {}
    },
    {
      "t": 1638416233,
      "f": 1073743361,
      "tp": "evt",
      "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.023335, 121.721730\nTime: 2021-12-02 11:37:13\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.023335,121.721730",
      "x": 121.721729978,
      "y": 17.0233349999,
      "rt": 0,
      "p": {}
    },
    {
      "t": 1638426180,
      "f": 1073743361,
      "tp": "evt",
      "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.023990, 121.721965\nTime: 2021-12-02 14:23:00\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.023990,121.721965",
      "x": 121.721965027,
      "y": 17.0239899993,
      "rt": 0,
      "p": {}
    },
    {
      "t": 1638430480,
      "f": 1073743361,
      "tp": "evt",
      "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.014735, 121.721372\nTime: 2021-12-02 15:34:40\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.014735,121.721372",
      "x": 121.721371651,
      "y": 17.0147350003,
      "rt": 0,
      "p": {}
    },
    {
      "t": 1638439534,
      "f": 1073743361,
      "tp": "evt",
      "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.014727, 121.721405\nTime: 2021-12-02 18:05:34\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.014727,121.721405",
      "x": 121.721405029,
      "y": 17.0147266666,
      "rt": 0,
      "p": {}
    },
    {
      "t": 1638450807,
      "f": 1073743361,
      "tp": "evt",
      "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Dalig, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.014760, 121.722102\nTime: 2021-12-02 21:13:27\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.014760,121.722102",
      "x": 121.722101657,
      "y": 17.0147599995,
      "rt": 0,
      "p": {}
    },
    {
      "t": 1638467462,
      "f": 1073743361,
      "tp": "evt",
      "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.015082, 121.721735\nTime: 2021-12-03 01:51:02\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.015082,121.721735",
      "x": 121.721735001,
      "y": 17.0150816669,
      "rt": 0,
      "p": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? If it is SQL Server 2016 or later, you can pass the entire JSON to a stored procedure to load all of it in one shot, i.e. bulk insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON in one shot.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9075d8cbc2e6dde76d26eff3730a4ba0)

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) =
N'[
    {
        "count": 8,
        "messages": [
            {
                "t": 1638413506,
                "f": 1073743361,
                "tp": "evt",
                "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.026467, 121.721675\nTime: 2021-12-02 10:51:46\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.026467,121.721675",
                "x": 121.721674983,
                "y": 17.0264666677,
                "rt": 0,
                "p": {}
            },
            {
                "t": 1638415192,
                "f": 1073743361,
                "tp": "evt",
                "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.023507, 121.721527\nTime: 2021-12-02 11:19:52\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.023507,121.721527",
                "x": 121.721526655,
                "y": 17.0235066672,
                "rt": 0,
                "p": {}
            },
            {
                "t": 1638416233,
                "f": 1073743361,
                "tp": "evt",
                "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.023335, 121.721730\nTime: 2021-12-02 11:37:13\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.023335,121.721730",
                "x": 121.721729978,
                "y": 17.0233349999,
                "rt": 0,
                "p": {}
            },
            {
                "t": 1638426180,
                "f": 1073743361,
                "tp": "evt",
                "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.023990, 121.721965\nTime: 2021-12-02 14:23:00\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.023990,121.721965",
                "x": 121.721965027,
                "y": 17.0239899993,
                "rt": 0,
                "p": {}
            },
            {
                "t": 1638430480,
                "f": 1073743361,
                "tp": "evt",
                "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.014735, 121.721372\nTime: 2021-12-02 15:34:40\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.014735,121.721372",
                "x": 121.721371651,
                "y": 17.0147350003,
                "rt": 0,
                "p": {}
            },
            {
                "t": 1638439534,
                "f": 1073743361,
                "tp": "evt",
                "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.014727, 121.721405\nTime: 2021-12-02 18:05:34\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.014727,121.721405",
                "x": 121.721405029,
                "y": 17.0147266666,
                "rt": 0,
                "p": {}
            },
            {
                "t": 1638450807,
                "f": 1073743361,
                "tp": "evt",
                "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Dalig, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.014760, 121.722102\nTime: 2021-12-02 21:13:27\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.014760,121.722102",
                "x": 121.722101657,
                "y": 17.0147599995,
                "rt": 0,
                "p": {}
            },
            {
                "t": 1638467462,
                "f": 1073743361,
                "tp": "evt",
                "et": "(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.015082, 121.721735\nTime: 2021-12-03 01:51:02\nhttp://maps.google.com/?q=17.015082,121.721735",
                "x": 121.721735001,
                "y": 17.0150816669,
                "rt": 0,
                "p": {}
            }
        ]
    }
]';

SELECT ISJSON(@json);

-- INSERT INTO <target table>
SELECT message.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json) as messages
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(messages.value, '$.messages') 
WITH
(
    t NVARCHAR(10) '$.t'
    , f NVARCHAR(10) '$.f'
    , tp NCHAR(3) '$.tp'
    , et NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.et' 
    , x NVARCHAR(20) '$.x'
    , y NVARCHAR(20) '$.y'
    , rt INT '$.rt'
    , p NVARCHAR(100) '$.p'
) 
AS message;
```

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak, i am using SQL 2018.  I tried running the script but i get an error saying Incorrect syntax near '$.t'.

Comment: My answer is following a **minimal reproducible example** pattern. Just copy it to SSMS as-is, run, and it will work. I added a Fiddle to the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak! I can see that your solution is perfectly working through the Fiddle you have provided and I love it! I think there is something missing in my SQL version hence the same error I am getting as I have mentioned earlier.   Sorry, I also mis-typed the version of my SQL, it should be 2017.  Odd still though, I tried changing the SQL version in the Fiddle and it still works fine.  Do you have any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: it works! I just altered the compatibility level of my database from 100 to 140 using below commands. Thank you Yitzhak and Skully! you are truly great! 

ALTER DATABASE {my database}
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140;

Comment: @SnakeBytes, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The response you are receiving from the website is in JSON, you can convert this to an array in PHP and iterate through every message and echo out whatever variable you like, along with saving it to a database.

```php
<?php

// The JSON below is fetched from the website's API endpoint.
$json = '{"count":8,"messages":[{"t":1638413506,"f":1073743361,"tp":"evt","et":"(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.026467, 121.721675\nTime: 2021-12-02 10:51:46\nhttp:\/\/maps.google.com\/?q=17.026467,121.721675","x":121.721674983,"y":17.0264666677,"rt":0,"p":{}},{"t":1638415192,"f":1073743361,"tp":"evt","et":"(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.023507, 121.721527\nTime: 2021-12-02 11:19:52\nhttp:\/\/maps.google.com\/?q=17.023507,121.721527","x":121.721526655,"y":17.0235066672,"rt":0,"p":{}},{"t":1638416233,"f":1073743361,"tp":"evt","et":"(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.023335, 121.721730\nTime: 2021-12-02 11:37:13\nhttp:\/\/maps.google.com\/?q=17.023335,121.721730","x":121.721729978,"y":17.0233349999,"rt":0,"p":{}},{"t":1638426180,"f":1073743361,"tp":"evt","et":"(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.023990, 121.721965\nTime: 2021-12-02 14:23:00\nhttp:\/\/maps.google.com\/?q=17.023990,121.721965","x":121.721965027,"y":17.0239899993,"rt":0,"p":{}},{"t":1638430480,"f":1073743361,"tp":"evt","et":"(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.014735, 121.721372\nTime: 2021-12-02 15:34:40\nhttp:\/\/maps.google.com\/?q=17.014735,121.721372","x":121.721371651,"y":17.0147350003,"rt":0,"p":{}},{"t":1638439534,"f":1073743361,"tp":"evt","et":"(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.014727, 121.721405\nTime: 2021-12-02 18:05:34\nhttp:\/\/maps.google.com\/?q=17.014727,121.721405","x":121.721405029,"y":17.0147266666,"rt":0,"p":{}},{"t":1638450807,"f":1073743361,"tp":"evt","et":"(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Dalig, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.014760, 121.722102\nTime: 2021-12-02 21:13:27\nhttp:\/\/maps.google.com\/?q=17.014760,121.722102","x":121.722101657,"y":17.0147599995,"rt":0,"p":{}},{"t":1638467462,"f":1073743361,"tp":"evt","et":"(NotificationNo: GPS0006)\nAlert!\n\nMOTION DETECTION: Tractor #16\n\nSuspicious movement of vehicle is detected while engine is off! \n\nCurrent Location: Bacnor East, Burgos, Isabela, Philippines\nCoordinates: 17.015082, 121.721735\nTime: 2021-12-03 01:51:02\nhttp:\/\/maps.google.com\/?q=17.015082,121.721735","x":121.721735001,"y":17.0150816669,"rt":0,"p":{}}]}';

$allMessages = json_decode($json, true); // Convert to associative array.

foreach($allMessages["messages"] as $i => $message) // Iterate through every message.
{
    // $message here now references each message within the data.
    // For this example, output the 'tp' of the message on a new line.
    echo "[Message " . $i . "] " . $message["tp"] . "<br><br>";

    // Insert further code here to save the $message into your SQL database.
}
```

For saving information to the database using a Microsoft SQL server, see: [Microsoft SQL Server for PHP - Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#getting-started)

Comment: Thanks Skully, it worked! Just figuring out the Bulk Insert to append the records into my table.